# Setting quotas from a Linux client on a SmartOS (OpenSolaris) based ZFS server

Tags: linux, nfs, quota, smartos

I have a SmartOS (an OS based on OpenSolaris) server running a few virtual machines.

One of the ZFS volumes is shared as an NFS volume and mounted on one of the VMs which is running Debian wheezy. The mount works fine through NFS v4. When I set quotas through the zfs userquota@user property, I can access the quota information on the Linux machine by running something like:

quota -u username -m -A -v

However, when I'm trying to update/set a quota from the Linux side, I'm getting a "Connection Refused" error.
I use the command:

edquota -r -m -u username

The Linux client has root rights on the NFS share. Is it even possible to set the quotas from Linux? If so, how to debug the "Connection refused" error?